# this is undefined in typescript class

Tags: node.js, typescript, this

I am trying to understand why "this" can be undefined in classes sometimes, and how to fix it:

```
import { UserDatabase } from './user.database';

export class UserService {
    private userDatabase = new UserDatabase();
    
    
    async login (request: Request, response: Response) {
        let {email, password} = request.body;
        
        const user = await this.userDatabase.login(email, password);
...
```

Error log:

`(node:3254) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'userDatabase' of undefined`

Answer (score 3):

The usual problem with the `this`.

You could bind the method to the class context:

```
export class UserService {
  constructor () {
    this.login = this.login.bind(this);
  }

  ...

}
```

Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind